# How to output a graph in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

How do I output a plot as a PNG file in Netlogo please? I don't mean the data that created the plot, which is export-plot, but the picture. I can do a screen shot but it seems like there might be a better way.

Answer (score 4):

You can write click on the plot and click "copy image" and paste it into an image software, word document, email, etc. You may also export the plot to a csv and use excel to create the graph.